# Remove properties from the object with value equal to zero

Tags: javascript, arrays, functional-programming

```
removeZero({ a: 0, b: 1, c: -1 })

output:

removeZero({ b: 1, c: -1 })
```

I'm trying to write a function in the functional programming approach which use just `map()`, `reduce()`, `filter()`. this was my best approach but it didn't work.

```
const removeZero = (item) => (
    Object
      .keys(item)
      .filter(Boolean)
      .map((key) => ({ [key]: item[key] }))
      .reduce((acc, curr) => ({ ...acc, ...curr }))
  )
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: So if this is meant to be functional, you aren't *removing* the properties so much as creating a new object with only the properties you want to keep, right?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yes exactly. you are right

Comment: the `reduce` create a new object

Comment: You are applying `.filter(Boolean)` to the property names, not the values. Also, your approach generates quite a few intermediate objects. A simply for loop or forEach would probably be "cheaper" (or what T.J. did ;) )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're pretty close. This works and is mostly functional (I think; I'm not at all steeped in the idioms of functional programming), but barring using `Object.defineProperty` to define the properties I think you're going to have to go imperative for the last step (setting the props):

```js
const removeZero = item => (
    Object
      .keys(item)
      .filter(key => item[key] !== 0)
      .reduce((newObj, key) => {
        newObj[key] = item[key];
        return newObj;
      }, {})
  );
const result = removeZero({ a: 0, b: 1, c: -1 });
console.log(result);
```

I suppose we could create a new object every time in the `reduce`, but it seems wasteful:

```js
const removeZero = item => (
    Object
      .keys(item)
      .filter(key => item[key] !== 0)
      .reduce((newObj, key) => ({
        ...newObj, [key]: item[key]
      }), {})
  );
const result = removeZero({ a: 0, b: 1, c: -1 });
console.log(result);
```

...but note that that relies on object spread notation, which is a Stage 3 [proposal](https://github.com/sebmarkbage/ecmascript-rest-spread) (and likely to be in ES2018) but is not in the spec yet.

---

naomik points out that we can avoid doing the

```
newObj[key] = item[key];
return newObj;
```

part without creating a new object by using `Object.assign`, like this:

```js
const removeZero = item => (
    Object
      .keys(item)
      .filter(key => item[key] !== 0)
      .reduce((newObj, key) => Object.assign(newObj, {[key]: item[key]}), {})
  );
const result = removeZero({ a: 0, b: 1, c: -1 });
console.log(result);
```

I'll leave it to more functional heads than mine whether that's more functional than the one setting the property and doing `return`. :-)

Comment: This avoids all the intermediate objects at least. Nice!

Comment: Good answer TJ. You could also use `Object.assign(newObj, { [key]: item[key] })` which avoids imperative assignment and need for object spread syntax ^_^

Comment: @T.J.Crowder sorry, it wasn't meant to be a criticism re: imperative style. I just mean we're lucky that `Object.assign` gives us the return value we need here which (I think) makes it a good fit

Comment: @naomik: Didn't take it as criticism. :-) (And *useful* criticism, such as I'd expect from you, is always gratefully received in any case.)

Answer (score 1):

Well you don't *need* the intermediate `.filter` or `.map` step. They read a bit nicer but add lots of unnecessary iteration in the process. You could write your function as a single reduce

```js
const removeZero = o =>
  Object.keys(o)
    .reduce((acc, k) => {
      if (o[k] === 0)
        return acc
      else
        return Object.assign(acc, { [k]: o[k] })
    }, {})

let output = removeZero({ a: 0, b: 1, c: -1 })
console.log(output)
```

Or if you like @TJCrowder's approach but want to dodge the imperative assignment or spread object proposal, you can use an `Object.assign` expression

```js
const removeZero = o =>
  Object.keys(o)
    .filter(k => o[k] !== 0)
    .reduce((acc, k) =>
      Object.assign(acc, { [k]: o[k] }), {})

let output = removeZero({ a: 0, b: 1, c: -1 })
console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks to T.J I've arrived to this solution:

```
const setProp = (item, key) => ({[key]: item[key]})

const removeZero = (item) => (
  Object
    .keys(item)
    .filter((key) => item[key])
    .reduce((acc, curr) => ({ ...acc, ...setProp(item, curr) }), {})
)
```

Comment: Note that your filter doesn't do what your problem statement says it should do. It removes all properties with *falsy* values, not properties with the value 0. (See also the second option I added to my answer just moments before you finished posting this, you don't need `setProp` if you don't want it.)